# Halt long running process in Struts 2

Tags: struts2, struts2-interceptors

I implemented `executeAndWait` Interceptor in Struts2 application and it is running fine. Is there any way to stop this long running process in between through interceptor? Can I limit maximum time to execute an action?

Comment: The process is running in a separate thread, so it's more like stopping a thread running in the background.